# Grabbing IP addresses from a file and counting the occurences

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, ip

I am quite new to python and got stuck while doing a school assignment. I am supposed to grab IP addresses from a file and then count the amount of times each IP appears and print out the result.

I keep getting an error: Unhashable Type: 'list'

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

def grab_ip(file):
    ips = []
    occurence = {}
    with open (file) as file:
        for ip in file:
            ips.append(re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', ip))
        for ipaddr in ips:
            if ipaddr in occurence:
                occurence[ipaddr] = occurence[ipaddr] + 1
            else:
                occurence[ipaddr] = 1
    for key, value in occurence.iteritems():
        print key, value
    return None
print grab_ip('FILE_WITH_IPS.txt')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall()` will return a list, so try anther loop with append:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

def grab_ip(file):
    ips = []
    occurence = {}
    with open (file) as file:
        for ip in file:
            ip_data=re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',ip)
            for i in ip_data:
                ips.append(i)
        for ipaddr in ips:
            if ipaddr in occurence:
                occurence[ipaddr] = occurence[ipaddr] + 1
            else:
                occurence[ipaddr] = 1
    for key, value in occurence.iteritems():
        print key, value
    return None
print grab_ip('data')
```

here is file data lines:

```
123.0.9.1
fjdakl
jfkal 23.2.2.9
```

the function return None

Answer (score 1):

You're totally there. Just use `extend` instead of `append` because the output of `findall` function must be a list. So appending a list to another list will produce list of list, that's why you got the error `Unhashable Type: 'list'`.

```
ips.extend(re.findall(r'\b(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\b', ip))
```